# Container not rendered on to the form

Tags: codenameone

I am facing a problem where in I have a container where the objects are drawn onto it, The container is added to form and the form is displayed. The form also contains ToolBar to show some menus. But the problem is that the container is rendered within the tool bar. I have given the size of the Container as 1020X590 but still it is rendering within the toolBar. Any help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) the layout manager determines the size of the components so you can give a component any size you want but it would be ignored as the layout manager places the components into place.

Use `BorderLayout` not box and add the container using:

```
form.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, container);
```

This will implicitly set the container to the full screen.

Comment: I did that but the objects are not rendered properly as in the above image, Before this, The object was rendered properly

Comment: The Codename One coordinate system per component starts at `getX()`/`getY()` not at 0, 0 like it does in Swing/AWT. Just make sure your code takes that into consideration and translates the coordinates it draws.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the answer of Shai, I would recommend re-validating the form if it has been already displayed, when adding the container.

```
form.revalidate();
```

Comment: Now am able to see the container at the center. But the Objects are distorted. The 2 images that were together, now they are not. Am Unable to solve this as I cant figure out what is the problem with the Game. Can anyone Look at my Code and help me with that. It is the problem with transformaions.